# Highcharts 3d resize zindex bug

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am having this issue with Highcharts 3d resize zindex series.

Please refer to https://jsfiddle.net/0eksh7w2/4/ and resize Result window. You will see a bug with zindex.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    "chart": {
        "type": "column",
        "_animation": false,
        "_margin": [100, 75, 75, 75],
        ...
```

I just reported the bug. Meanwhile, does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: It should be already fixed on the master branch: http://github.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js

Comment: I saw your comment after I posted an answer. It's fixed now, thank you very much. When will we have a release?

Comment: Release date isn't specified. It should be probably by the end of the April.

Answer (score 0):

This bug is now fixed.

Please refer to https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4062

See code working at: http://jsfiddle.net/0eksh7w2/7/

```
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.src.js"></script>
...
```